# Pandas, Combine string columns with conditions, but get The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I want to join Pandas DataFrame columns with conditions -- separate the columns with a comma only if the ending one is not empty:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score':np.random.randn(3),
                   'person1':[x*3 for x in list('ABC')],
                  'person2':[x*3 for x in list('DEF')]})
df

df['person2'][1]=""
#print(df['person1']+("" if df['person2']=="" else ", "+df['person2']) )
#print(df['person1']+("" if not df['person2'] else ", "+df['person2']) )
#print(df['person1']+("" if not df['person2'].values else ", "+df['person2']) )
# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

However, all the suggestions from the search hits that I got don't work. All my above attempts ended up with the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

PS, considering that I'm joining multiple columns, and some of them maybe blank, and I don't want to end up with a string of multiple commas, is it possible to write a function so that I just call that function when joining multiple columns?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a function to every row like this:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.person1 + (',' + row.person2 if row.person2 else ''),
         axis=1)
```